# Extract username with regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Extracting the username from this string?

```
<title>[FirstName] [SecondName] (@[Username]) on [Site]</title>
```

I tried using regex but it gives me:

> Object reference not found exception.

This is the code I use:

```
return Regex.Matches(title, @"\(([^)]*)\)").OfType<Match>().LastOrDefault().ToString();
```

Comment: Try `Regex.Matches(title, @"(?<=\()([^()]+)(?=\))").Cast<Match>().LastOrDefault().ToString()`

Comment: Please give a real example. In this it's hard to see if the [ ] around each item are supposed to be part of the actual case or not.

Comment: Also, if you want to avoid errors, _always_ be prepared to handle cases in which the input is not found. LastOrDefault will indeed return `null` if nothing was found, which throws a nullpointer exception if you try to call `ToString` on it.

Comment: Also note that your code returns the _whole_ match, including the brackets, and not capture group #1.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            string input = "<title>[FirstName] [SecondName] (@[Username]) on [Site]</title>";

            string pattern = @"\[(?'value'[^\]]+)\]";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            Console.WriteLine("User Name : '{0}'", matches[2].Groups["value"].Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract `Username` from `<title>[FirstName] [SecondName] (@[Username]) on [Site]</title>` you could capture in a group what is between `(@[` and `])` by using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches not a a closing square bracket one or more times `[^]+`:

[`\(@\[([^\]]+)\]\)`](https://regex101.com/r/4dGbna/1)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KTDAY82051)

Or use a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) the asserts what is on the left side is `(@[` and a positive lookahead that asserts what is on the right side is `])`:

[`(?<=\(@\[)[^]]+(?=\]\))`](https://regex101.com/r/4dGbna/2)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OSJN45509)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I03muR) and it works:

```
var match = Regex.Matches("<title>[FirstName] [SecondName] (@[Username]) on [Site]</title>", @"\(([^)]*)\)")
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .LastOrDefault()
                 .ToString();
```

The only difference with your code is that I'm not using `title` variable. So you `title` variable may be `null`, or empty or doesn't contains any match so you may end up with `LastOrDefault().ToString();` failing because you're calling `ToString()` on a `null` reference (`LastOrDefault` returns `null` when you're dealing with an empty collection of reference types).

To fix the error just refactor your code like below:

```
var match = Regex.Matches("<title>[FirstName] [SecondName] (@[Username]) on [Site]</title>", @"\(([^)]*)\)")
                 .OfType<Match>()?
                 .LastOrDefault()?
                 .ToString();
```

The code after `?` character will be called only when the result is not `null`.